# angular-material highlightClass for mdToast not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to implement Toast messages in my angular app which uses angular-material library.

```
    app.service('ToastFlash', ['$mdToast', function($mdToast) {
      this.showMessage = function(message, $event) {
        $mdToast.show(
          $mdToast
          .simple()
          .textContent(message)
          .action("Dismiss")
          .highlightAction(true)
          .highlightClass('md-accent')
        );
      };
    }]);
```

For some reason this is giving me error when I call `showMessage()` as : 
`TypeError: $mdToast.simple(...).textContent(...).action(...).highlightAction(...).highlightClass is not a function`. 
When I remove the highlightClass line, it works perfectly. 
Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the latest material version `v1.1.0-rc.5` js and css file,

```
$scope.showToast = function() {
        var toast = $mdToast.simple()
          .content('Hello world')
          .action('OK')
          .highlightAction(true)
          .position('left top right')
           .highlightClass('md-warn');
      $mdToast.show(toast);
    };
```

Here is the working [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/xbwtd3cf/56/)

Comment: I am on 1.0.9...will that be the issue ? @Sajeetharan

Comment: change the file and check in the same fiddle

Comment: @SiDDevesh did it help?